# Does 'there exists' mean 'there is at least one'?

Tags: word-usage, semantics

If we say 'there exists a man called John' does this imply there is a particular man in mind? Or do I mean, 'there exists (at least one) man called john', e.g If I know there is numerous people called John, is it correct to say 'there exists a man called John'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135387/discussion-on-question-by-user1007028-does-there-exists-mean-there-is-at-leas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In everyday English

> There exists a man...

means that you're talking about a particular man (whose attributes are presumably mentioned in the ellipses).

But if there were other men with these same attributes, that fact would not invalidate the  primary meaning. This implies that 'There exists...' allows multiple possible men like this.

This extended implication is what 'there exists' means explicitly in math and logic, that 'there exists...' is the same as 'there is at least one...'. But informally this is a little surprising since, by pragmatics, if you wanted the listener to know about these other possibilities. you would explicitly refer to them by saying 'there is at least one'.

This shows the difference between natural language and stipulated mathematical language. If someone says 'there exists a man that ...' the hearer assumes that there is only one such man, even though logically having more isn't inconsistent.

A lot of this is bound up in the article 'a/an'. If you say "I have a dollar in my pocket" when in fact you have two dollars, you're not wrong (technically speaking), but if other find out you have two dollars, people might think it weird, like you're trying to hide something.

Comment: But the converse is definitely not the case. That is, if you say you have two dollars when you have no more than one, then you are definitely lying.

Comment: So If I say, 'I have a dollar' when in fact I have two, I'm talking about a particular one of those dollars? I.e. it would not make sense to talk about the existence of a single dollar, when you have two (you could say perhaps, that I could take out a single dollar) without having one particular dollar in mind? Where in Logic we will say 'there exists an x' where we are talking about the existence of at least one of the solution e.g. I'm just saying there's at least once, that 'x' is not a particular value.

Comment: "If I say, 'I have a dollar' when in fact I have two, I'm talking about a particular one of those dollars?" No, "I have a dollar" implies that you have at least one dollar. You're not specifying a particular object, just the count. This is the technical meaning of "I have a dollar" - most people would take this statement to mean "I have exactly one dollar".

Comment: Similarly with "There exists a man called John" - in technical/mathematical terms, there's no particular man involved, you're just stating a fact about people and names. But in normal speaking, yes, you are trying to communicate to others that there is this one particular man named John.

Comment: Thank you, why does this phrase have this meaning? having 3 three things means you have at least one thing? is this the idea behind this? It seems out of the usual for how we use 'a man' in a phrase.

Comment: The short answer is that natural language with normal speaking make certain unconscious inferences and then math extracts those meanings, puts them in symbols, and it takes a life of its own there, where the definitions are stipulated to make things easier to manipulate symbolically. So the obvious usage can diverge between natural language and math. It seems weird, but  that's what the math does. To be clear, when we usually talk, 'there exists' and 'a man' are referring to a single person. It's only in the rarefied logical thought of math where it has these non-obvious implications.

Answer (score 2):

No, the sentence

- *There exists a man called John*

does not entail, presuppose, conversationally implicate, or invite the inference that there's only one man named John. You can't do that so simply. Using a definite article

- *There exists the man called John*

doesn't do that -- it identifies one man named John, but it doesn't say there aren't others, only one that is the topic of the sentence.

*There exists* is one of the English versions of the Existential Quantifier, symbolized in logic with the character **∃**, an upside-down capital E for 'Exists'. Its use in a formula presupposes the existence of whatever variable it binds. For example,

- ∃x ((Man x) AND (Name x, John))

says that there exists some variable x such that x is a man and x is named John. At least one such, not only one such. Other English versions include *there is/are* itself -- *exists* is implicit in the meaning. Of course English is hardly logic, but it contains everything that logic does.

Comment: there exists 'some variable x' sounds like there is one variable x, should it be 'there exists at least one value of the variable x'? It makes sense to see it as a linguistic version of the quantifier, its just saying 'there's a man at the door' implies you have one man, where saying 'there exists a man called john' sounds as if there is a particular man called john and you are saying he exists in the same way, where as 'there exists at least one man called john makes sense, but we use commonly 'there exists a man called john' to say essentially 'there exists a least one man called john'

Comment: That's one way to specify it, but it's not what _there exists_ means.